# iOS - How to have all facebook friends pre-selected for app request?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-app-requests

I have facebook app request implemented in my iOS app and I want all friends to be selected by default and let the user to deselect friends instead. Can we do that in iOS ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi! did u find any solution to your question?